# Environment Variable Not Visible when Evaluating a Function with a Sub-shell

Tags: bash, function, eval

This is a minimal example of a more complex script I'm writing. The key thing I want to do is have `$FOO` visible to that sub shell in the second line of function `foo`.

However, as shown, it's not visible for the first evaluation but oddly visible for the second evaluation.

```
❯ function foo() {
  echo "export FOO=BAR"
  echo "export CAR=\$(echo \$FOO)"
}

~
❯ eval $(foo)

~
❯ echo $CAR

~
❯ eval $(foo)

~
❯ echo $CAR
BAR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eval $(foo)` is expanded to:

```
eval 'export FOO=BAR export CAR=$(echo $FOO)'
```

The `export` has the effect of causing both assignments to be processed 'at the same time' and since `FOO` is not known prior to this line of code the second assignment becomes `CAR=$(echo '')=''`. It's only on the 2nd `eval $(foo)` that `FOO` has a value so `CAR=BAR`.

To get around this side effect and have `CAR=BAR` (for the first `eval $(foo)`) you can either remove the `export` or have the function print a `;` between the two `export`s (explicitly separate the `export`s as two separate commands), eg:

```
# remove 'export'

foo() {
  echo "FOO=BAR"
  echo "CAR=\$(echo \$FOO)"
}

# explicitly separate into 2 commands via a ';'

foo() {
  echo "export FOO=BAR ;"                # notice the ';' appended on the end
  echo "export CAR=\$(echo \$FOO)"
}
```

For the 2nd `foo()` definition the `eval $(foo)` is expanded to:

```
eval 'export FOO=BAR ; export CAR=$(echo $FOO)'
```

With two separate commands `FOO` is assigned a value before we parse/execute `CAR=$(echo $FOO)`.

---

We can see this behavior of `export` with a simpified example (sans the issues mentioned in Gordon Davisson's comment):

```
$ export A=3 B="$A"
$ typeset -p A B
declare -x A="3"
declare -x B=""              # A does not have a value so B=""

$ export A=3 B="$A"
$ typeset -p A B
declare -x A="3"
declare -x B="3"             # A now has a value (from 1st run) so B=3
```

Comment: Unquoted variable and command substitutions, and `eval` are both open invitations for trouble, and using them together like this is almost guaranteed to be a problem. I'd recommend refactoring the script to avoid the need for `eval`, and also being careful to double-quote all expansions. [Shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at pointing out missing quotes, but avoiding `eval` is generally beyond its capabilities.

Comment: Gordan, I agree that I could just not use `eval` but this is one of those "eval to set the proper env vars patter".